How can I retain C# WinForms UserControl information?
On the main form, I have a menu on the left side, and a "Panel" on the right side. For certain things, I have a usercontrol form.
When clicking "computers", I have it run the below code.
var ComputersUserPanel = new ComputersPanel(site);
ContentPanel.Controls.Clear();
ContentPanel.Controls.Add(ComputersUserPanel);

When this loads, the ComputerPanel will run a SQL function to get all the computers for a site. Now this can be a lot which is the issue. Every time I click a different menu item then click computers menu item again, it runs the above again, which can be a lot. I want it to run once then cache that information somehow.
The secondary issue is, loading and caching 1 site would be fine, but this could be multiple, meaning the same computer user control form is using for multiple sites and the have to be sperate.


Why create a new user control every time? Why not just create a new one the first time, then reuse it on later occasions? You could declare a field of that type and check whether it's null. If it is, create a new control and assign it to that field. If it's not, use that control.

One approach might be to create a computer caching service class as follows:
The service would offer a method to get computers for a given site. If the site is not yet in the cache, it performs the SQL and add the list to its cache before returning the result, otherwise it just returns what it found from the cache.
The cache could be implemented as a dictionary in which the key identifies the site and the value is some collection (array, list, whatever) of computers.
Now ComputerPanel, instead of directly executing your SQL just calls the caching service.
// Simple caching service
public class ComputersCache
{
    private Dictionary<string,List<Computer>> _cache = new Dictionary<string,List<Computer>>();

    private Func<string,List<Computer>> _getterFunc;

    public ComputersCache(Func<string,List<Computer>> getterFunc)
    {
        _getterFunc = getterFunc;
    }

    public List<Computer> GetComputers(string site)
    {
        if (!_cache.TryGetValue(site, out var computers))
        {
            computers = _getterFunc(site);
            _cache.Add(site, computers);
        }

        return computers;
    }
}

// Wrapper around your SQL
public List<Computer> GetComputers(string site)
{
    // Your SQL request goes here
}

// One-time setup of the cache service (could be static):
ComputersCache ComputersCache = new ComputersCache(GetComputers);

// Usage:
var computers = ComputersCache.GetComputers(site);


I did it like this:
//create global variable for your user control
ComputersUserPanel _ucComputer = null;
        
//then in you treeview item click event
if (_ucComputer == null)
{
    _ucComputer = new ComputersUserPanel(site);
}
    
ContentPanel.Controls.Clear();
ContentPanel.Controls.Add(_ucComputer);

